# Can't get max ram size - STM32 with rtos

Tags: stm32

i'm using STM32F103R8T6,I'm currently setting max heap size for RTOS

When i try setting 12000

```
#define configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE                    ((size_t)12000)
```

ERROR Compilation

```
region `RAM' overflowed by 780 bytes    Project-STM32           C/C++ Problem
```

so what's the max i can use ?

Comment: It also depends on the variables out of the RTOS you have. You can check how much is assigned to each variable in the .map file, in the output directory. I think you also have to add the stack_size (defined in the .ld file) to the used RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the linker (.ld) file.  You'll see section defining RAM.  That will tell you how much RAM you have, assuming the linker file was properly generated.

Comment: it's generated using CUBEMX, MEMORY
{
RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 20K
FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x8000000, LENGTH = 64K
}

Comment: This means that your RAM usage exceeds 20K defined in the linker file.

Comment: If you're using gcc toolsuite, run this _arm-none-eabi-size_ on your ELF file.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you've pasted indicates that linker went 780 bytes past the end of available RAM area. In your case (STM32F103R8T6), it tried to place 21260 bytes (20KB + 780) into RAM which is defined to only fit 20KB. If you decrease `configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE` by the amount reported by linker, it'll likely link successfully. There will however be 0 remaining space for regular / non-RTOS heap so no `malloc` or `new` will succeed, in case any part of your code wanted to use it.

You can determine exactly what gets put into RAM by your linker by analyzing your *.map file (sidenote: map file is created only if your program gets linked successfully, so you need to at least get it to that state). When you open it, search for `20000000` (start of your RAM region) and there you should see what exactly gets put there, including size of each chunk.

Unless you did something out-of-ordinary to your project (which I think is safe to assume you didn't as you mention using generated project), your RAM area during linking will need to at least fit the following sections:

- `.data` segment where things like global variables initialized by value live
- `.bss` segment which is similar to the one above except values are zero-initialized. This is where eventually the byte array of size `configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE` will be put that RTOS uses as its own heap
- Stack (don't confuse with RTOS stack sizes, this one is totally separate) - stack used outside of RTOS tasks. This has a constant size - consult your `sections.ld` file to find the value.
- Heap segment that has a size calculated dynamically by the linker and which is equal to total size of RAM minus size of all other sections. The bigger you make your other segments, the smaller your regular heap will be.

Having said that, apart from going through the *.map file to determine what else other than the RTOS heap occupies your RAM, I'd also think twice about why you'd need 12KB (out of 20KB total) assigned only to RTOS heap. Things like do you need so many tasks, do they need such large stacks, do you need so many/so large queues/mutexes/semaphores.